# Writing a model for a join table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables and want to create one in the middle just to link them together in a one-to-many fashion, and I have not done this before in Rails.

**Scenario**
Say I have the tables *Toolbox* and *Tool*. How would I go about generating a model for the linking table?

So far I thought of `rails g Model ToolboxTool toolbox:references tool:references`.

Is this the way to go or is there a better way?

Comment: Post your `Toolbox` and `Tool` models with their associations.

Comment: Did you look [at the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)?

Comment: If you want one-to-many and not many-to-many, you don't necessarily need a new join table. More information is needed on your actual relationships. Read the documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many